# Setting a cookie in ASP.Net, but jQuery seems to ignore it

Tags: jquery, asp.net, cookies

I have an ASP.NET app that's using jQuery and a home-made tab panel (long story) to preserve the current tab between postbacks.  I'm using the Cookie add-in.  It works very nicely and reliably.

We added a feature where clicking a link on one tab ("A") caused the server to do some stuff that changed the display on another tab ("B").  So the users wanted tab B to be current when the page returned.  The simplest thing to do seemed to be to have ASP.Net set the current-tab cookie to the value for tab B.  I did this with this code:

```
Response.SetCookie(New HttpCookie("current-tab", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("#Tabs-Planning")))
```

This works fine on my machine, but on the test server, it doesn't.  And here are the weird bits (the context is the test server, unless stated otherwise):

- jQuery continues to load and set the cookie reliably; it just acts as if the server-set cookie never happened.  If you click the button on tab A, the cookie you retrieve on reload shows tab A as the current tab, even though the server set the cookie to Tab B.
- I know that it did so, or did *something*, because the IE Developer Tools show the cookie as containing the value for tab B.
- No matter what tab you click on, the Developer Tools will show the cookie containing the value for tab B.  (I am clicking the menu option to view cookies repeatedly, not refreshing the cookie-display page, so I should always get current cookies.)  However, if you were on Tab A when you posted back, debugging the Javascript will show that the retrieved value is Tab A.
- No matter which method set the cookie, the cookie-display page shows the cookie as having a domain of ".com".  Obviously this is not the actual domain.
- I can see no difference between the cookies set by my machine and the cookies set by the test server, aside from the domain.
- I can see no difference between the cookies set by the server and the cookies set by jQuery.

I've tried everything I can think of.  Is there a server-settings or caching thing that could account for this?  I've never had occasion to set cookies in ASP.Net before:  perhaps there's something I need to set that I don't know about?

ETA:  I've since discovered [this behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862608/jquery-cookie-plug-in-behavior-is-setting-domain-to-com-if-cookie-is-session), and also that part of the problem was that on the test server the application was down a directory from the root, so that the server needed to set the path (it was getting automatically set on the client.)

This sorted the problem out on Chrome, but I'm still having the same problem on IE.  I've been instructed to focus on other things for now and return to it later in the week.

Comment: Is it possible that the HttpOnly property on your cookie is being set to true? That could explain the value being sent to the client but jQuery being unaware of the new value.

Comment: @rossisdead Good idea, but it turns out that it's set to false.  I've updated the question with things I've found out since posting.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the expires and the path properties to your cookie, and see if that helps.