# jQuery Cookie plug in behavior: is setting domain to ".com" if cookie is session cookie

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, cookies

Folks,

I've found that the jQuery cookie plugin is setting the domain to ".com" if the cookie I'm setting is a session cookie.

Here's the code:

```
jQuery.cookie("currentTab", selectedTab );
```

If I look at cookies with IE's Developer Tool, it shows the domain as ".com".

If I set this way:

```
jQuery.cookie("currentTab", selectedTab, { expires: 1} );
```

... then it has "www.sitename.com" as the domain.

Is there some trick I'm missing, or have I found a bug?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it this plugin? http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes. Looking at it I can't see why I would get the behavior I'm getting.

Comment: Maybe it's IEDT bug? :) Try Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: @Shoham Fair point.  I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Can you provide a demo page that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Y.Shoham It doesn't seem to happen on Chrome.  I haven't tried Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've created this http://jsfiddle.net/jvDXZ/ and checked it in Chrome and Firefox (Web Developer Tool > Cookies > View Cookie Information), and they had `fiddle.jshell.net` for both cookies. In IE8 IEDT is telling me he can't find the cookie file (?) on all the pages I've checked.

You can check in your IE if the cookie is accessible via other `.com` domain. If it's not (but you *can* access it via your `www.sitename.com`) - it's clearly IEDT bug.

Comment: @YShoham Thank you!  I've been told to focus on other things for now and come back to it later in the week, but I will update with the results when I have them.  Thanks again!